# Actividades en vez de Fragments en las Pestañas (TABS)

Tags: java, android

Mi actividad principal, llamada `HomeActivity`, contiene un `DrawerLayout` con un `NavigationView`, también contiene un `TabLayout` de 4 elementos con un `ViewPager`, pero este carga `Fragments` en su `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` (varios de estos contienen `RecyclerView`) y en el `mismo Thread (Principal)`, **mi intención** es **cargar Activities en vez de Fragments** como contenido de cada `pestaña (Tab)` para que así se ejecuten en `diferentes Threads` (o eso tengo entendido) y no en el `Thread principal` consumiendo la app.

Pregunta: ¿Cómo ejecutar `Activities` en vez de `Fragments` en cada `Tab` y qué cada una esté en un `Thread diferente`?

[image: Imagen]

```
private void rellenarViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    AdaptadorSecciones adapter = new AdaptadorSecciones(getFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentNoticies(), getString(R.string.fr_noticiies));
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentComercos(), getString(R.string.fr_comercos));
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentOfertes(), getString(R.string.fr_ofertes));
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentServeis(), getString(R.string.fr_serveis);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public class AdaptadorSecciones extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> fragmentos = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> titulosFragmentos = new ArrayList<>();

    public AdaptadorSecciones(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragmentos.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentos.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment, String title) {
        fragmentos.add(fragment);
        titulosFragmentos.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titulosFragmentos.get(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ddenis mi pregunta es porque Activities en lugar de Fragments?

Comment: Reformulo la pregunta: ¿Cómo ejecutar Activities en vez de Fragments en cada Tab y qué cada una esté en un Thread diferente?

Comment: @ddenis, por lo que comentas "en un thread diferente" estas teniendo problemas  de bloqueo en tu UI?

Comment: @Elenasys Sí, los estoy teniendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Usar Activities en tabs es obsoleto**, lo correcto es cargar `Fragments` en lugar de `Activities`, en realidad el cargado de cada `Fragment` no debería afectar el Thread principal.

De hecho revisa la documentación :

> **TabActivity**: This class was deprecated in API level 13. New applications should use Fragments instead of this class; to continue
>   to run on older devices, you can use the v4 support library which
>   provides a version of the Fragment API that is compatible down to DONUT (Android 1.6.).

Ahora con respecto a tu pregunta:

> Como ejecuto cada Fragment que invoca el ViewPager en un Thread
>   diferente?

Puedes tener un fragment principal donde cargarías los fragmentos que se agregarían en los tabs a travez del adapter (Justo lo que estas realizando), dentro de este fragmento puedes llamar tu método `rellenarViewPager()` desde   `onViewCreated()` .

```
 @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.miViewpager);
        if (viewPager != null) {
            rellenarViewPager(viewPager);
        }
      ...
      ...
```

Comment: ¿Este método me asegura que cada fragment que se ejecute estará en un `Thread distinto` del principal? Haciendo algo así digo: 
    **if (fragmentoGenerico != null) {
            fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.contenedor_principal, fragmentoGenerico)
                    .commit();
        }**

Comment: Perdón por tardar en contestar tarde, así es, no debe bloquearse la UI cuando se cargan los fragmentos, pienso que seguramente tienes un proceso en algún fragmento que pudiera estar causando un ANR. http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html